# Automating Google Forms FIlling and Submission using Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation, google-forms

I have been trying to create a script that allows me to fill and submit a Google Form using Python. I use Selenium Web Driver for the same. It works fine when the Form dosen't require us to login. But when a Form reuires us to be logged in before accessing it, Google dosen't allo me to login and identifies that the browser is a web driver and asks to use a proper brower... Is there any way to get around this?

The code is below

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

web = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver')

web.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeRTrUApzzGYOzxBCf-0gJjWkK2OFMlZ10pZxWKHl9iS-2WuQ/viewform')

time.sleep(2)

input('Check if working')
```

Below are the screenshots of the error

[Signin Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLPcF.png)

[Error saying, this is not a valid browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtlSZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is Not good option for this matter.
To avoid being detected you should use a proper headers while sending a request with script.

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your google form to anyone on the internet, then you can access the form by selenium browser

[image]